# How do I return a 4xx or 5xx error response in a .NET Webhook Handler?

Tags: asp.net, webhooks, http-status-codes

I am currently implementing a WebHookHandler using Microsoft.AspNet.WebHooks. I have the hook running well, but I need to be able to return a 5xx or 4xx error response.

The samples only show a return in the ExecuteAsync method:

```
        return Task.FromResult(true);
```

I tried returning false in my exception handler, but the sender still sees the error as an acknowledgement and receives a 200 OK.  I would like the sender to receive an error code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `Response` property of the `WebHookHandlerContext` argument passed to the  `ExecuteAsync` method to set the `HttpResponseMessage` explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

This is a way you can do it:

```
public override Task ExecuteAsync(string receiver, WebHookHandlerContext webHookContext)
        {
            //Throw exception is a way
            //throw new Exception("Exception will be returned if uncomment this section");
            var response = new System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK);
            response.Content = new System.Net.Http.StringContent("Custom response");
            webHookContext.Response = response;
            return Task.FromResult(true);
}
```